# Removing row from primefaces datatable breaks the page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

So, I have 2 tables, `table1` and `table2`. For both of them, I have 2 buttons to add a row and to delete a row.
I can only add or remove rows in `table1` if I don't have any rows in `table2`, and I use `#{myBean.table2HasRows}` to test this.

So I enter in the page. I have 5 rows in `table1` and 2 rows in `table2`. I can add or delete rows in `table2` normally. Then I delete the 2 rows form `table2` so I can remove the rows in `table1`.
When I'm able to add or delete rows in `table1`, I can add normally, and I can also delete the rows I just added normally. But when I delete any of the rows of `table1` **that was loaded when I entered in the page** (in the bean I remove one object from the `#{myBean.table1RowRepresentationList}` list), the row is deleted ok, but then everything in the page stops working. I can't add or remove any other rows, and I can't use any other button in the page, the bean won't be called anymore. 
No errors are displayed in the console...

What could be happening?

Thanks!

```
<h:form>
    <table width="1150x">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelPublicacao" value="Table 1 " /> 
                <h:outputLabel value="Table 1 description" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">

                <h:panelGrid id="table1Panel" columns="2"   styleClass="panelGridTop">

                    <p:dataTable 
                        id="table1" 
                        var="table1Var"
                        value="#{myBean.table1RowRepresentationList}"
                        editable="true" editMode="cell" style="align:center;" styleClass="geralBorderless">

                        <p:column headerText="" style="width:20px; " >
                            <p:commandLink 
                                action="#{myBean.deleteTable1Row}"
                                update="table1,:form:wrongOption" 
                                id="removeButton"
                                disabled="#{myBean.table2HasRows}"
                                >
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/delete.gif" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{table1Var}"
                                    target="#{myBean.table1RowRepresentation}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Número de questões" style="width:70px;text-align:center">
                            <p:inputMask 
                                value="#{table1Var.numberQuestions}"
                                style="width:25px;" 
                                id="questionsField"
                                mask="9?9"
                                disabled="#{myBean.table2HasRows}" 
                            />

                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Error points" style="width:65px;text-align:center" rendered="#{myBean.wrongType}">
                            <p:inputText 
                                value="#{table1Var.wrongField}"
                                style="width:25px;" 
                                id="wrongPointsField"
                                onkeyup="formatDecimal(this);"
                                disabled="#{!myBean.wrongType}" 
                                >
                                <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <p:commandButton value="ADD ROW" 
                                    update="table1,wrongOption" 
                                    id="addRowTable1Button"
                                    actionListener="#{myBean.addRowForTabl1}"                                
                                    disabled="#{myBean.table2HasRows}" 
                                />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                </h:panelGrid>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel styleClass="labelPublicacao"
                    value="Table 2 " /> <h:outputLabel
                    value="Description of table 2" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h:panelGrid id="table2Panel" columns="2" width="670" styleClass="panelGridTop">

                    <p:dataTable 
                        id="table2" 
                        var="table2Var"
                        value="#{myBean.table2RowRepresentationList}"
                        editable="true" 
                        editMode="cell" 
                        style="align:center;" 
                        styleClass="geralBorderless">

                        <p:column headerText="" style="width:20px;">
                            <p:commandLink 
                                action="#{myBean.deleteTable2Row}" 
                                update="table2, :form:table1Panel" 
                                id="remove3Button">
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/delete.gif" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                    value="#{table2Var}"
                                    target="#{myBean.table2RowRepresentation}" />
                            </p:commandLink>                                    
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Name" >
                            <p:inputText
                                value="#{table2Var.concursoBook.name}"
                                style="width:140px;" 
                                id="nameField" 
                            />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Modal buttons" style="width:290px;text-align: center;">
                            <p:commandButton value="Modal 1" 
                                id="modal2Button" 
                                oncomplete="modal2.show();" 
                                styleClass="internalButton">
                            </p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton value="Modal 2" 
                                id="modal1Button" 
                                oncomplete="modal2.show();" 
                                styleClass="internalButton">
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:commandButton value="ADD ROW" 
                        update="table2, table1, :form:table1Panel, addRowTable1Button"
                        id="addRowTable2Button"
                        action="#{myBean.addRowForTable2}"
                    />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</h:form>
```

Comment: instead of using <table> use panel grid.

Comment: Debug and see if any errors are there in the consolde (Web brwoser debug using firebug).

Comment: The only error I have in the chrome browser console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clearTimeout' of null` that throws everytime I scroll the page.. but I don't think that's the problem... It's very strange the `table2` is very similar to `table1`. Why only in `table1` this happens?

Comment: post your managed bean code.